# How to escape parentheses with li:textequals

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

UPDATE:  Added the textEquals selector code.

I am using jquery and autocomplete for a field in my web application.

I have a "change" event that ensures the user chose a valid value from the autocomplete list.  This event works great except when there are parentheses in the chosen value the li:textequals selector does not work.

How do I escape the parentheses in the text that I'm searing for with li:textequals?

```
    change: function (event, ui) {
        //if the value of the textbox does not match a suggestion, clear its value             
        if ($(".ui-autocomplete li:textEquals('" + $(this).val() + "')").size() == 0) {
            $(this).val('');
        };
```

textEquals selector code:

```
$.expr[':'].textEquals = function (a, i, m) {
    return $(a).text().match("^" + m[3] + "$"); 
};
```

Comment: Where is `textEquals` coming from? I don't see it as a selector according to jQuey docs? http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but the jQuery docs suggest two backslashes:

> If you wish to use any of the meta-characters ( such as `!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^{|}~` ) as a literal part of a name, you must escape the character with two backslashes: \. For example, if you have an element with `id="foo.bar"`, you can use the selector `$("#foo\\.bar")`.

So in your case it might need to be:

```
var val = $(this).val()
    .replace("(", "\\(")
    .replace(")", "\\)");
if ($(".ui-autocomplete li:textEquals('" + val + "')").size() == 0) {
    $(this).val('');
};
```

Comment: The problem is the textEquals selector. It uses a regular expression to do it's match, and the ( ) are breaking it. you can use ( and ) in the usual jquery selectors such as :contains without issues. More than likely we can come up with a way to fix the selector itself so that it works just like other jquery selectors.

Comment: @KevinB - yes, he needs to post what code is being used for that. nrabinowitz's answer is great for the jQuery side, but I don't think there is any guarantee it will play nice with whatever code he is using to extend pseudoselectors.

Comment: nrabinowitz - This is working perfectly so far.  Thanks so much!

Comment: I'm not following your conversation entirely. To be clear, I copied this code from an autocomplete example somewhere.  I'm not sure I know what is meant by "extend pseudoselectors".

Comment: @BenFinkel - jQuery has a number of built-in pseudoselectors. These are preceded by a colon. So for example `li:first` grabs the first `li.` It makes use of the `first` pseudoselector. The one you are using, `:textEquals` is not native to jQuery, but has been added by you. Probably using something like `$.expr[ ":" ] ...`. The code in that extension method could be very important to ensuring an accurate answer to this question.

Comment: @mrtsherman - Thank you, I searched around and found that code (updated my post).  Didn't even realize I had added it, which I guess is what I get for cutting and pasting.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to injecting external input into your jQuery selectors, you can use the [`each()` method](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to loop on `<li>` items until you find a match:

```
change: function (event, ui) {
    var referenceValue = $(this).val();
    var matches = false;

    $(".ui-autocomplete li").each(function(){
        if( $(this).text()==referenceValue ){
            matches = true;
            return false;
        }
    });

    if(!matches){
        $(this).val('');
    }
}
```

Comment: So this particular filter would not accomplish what he's looking for, you'd need to add a .length to the end of it, and add an if statement.  Your code, as is would actually clear out values in any matching list items, as opposed to clearing out the textbox value if it didn't match a list item.

Comment: @PriorityMark - You are right, I misunderstood the question. I've updated my answer. Whatever, I hope it can at least help to find an alternative approach.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a better `:textEquals` custom selector that doesn't rely on a regexp, allowing you to use whatever characters you want within the parenthesis.

```
$.expr[':'].textEquals = function(a, i, m) {
    return $(a).text() === m[3];
};
alert($("div:textEquals('foo(bar)')").length);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Tentonaxe/77TVF/

Comment: I was going to suggest a variation of the filter, but this seems like a better option.

Comment: Using `.filter` is almost always faster than using custom selectors, but custom selectors are usually easier to read and therefore maintain.

Comment: @Kevin B - I marked the above as the answer, since it technically answered my question.  Having learned what I have however this is the solution I'm actually going to implement.  I have no need for the RegEx complexity in my code, it was just a part of the copy-n-paste that I used.  Thanks!